# Cursor changes over autocomplete list items

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I use jquery-ui's autocomplete feature on an input field. I understand that autocomplete creates a list of items that have the `<a>` tag. However, when the cursor hovers over a list item, it becomes a text selector (vertical bar). Is there some way I can make the cursor remain unchanged?

```
var phases=["Requirements gathering","Design","Development","Testing","Maintenance"]
$("#phase").autocomplete({source:phases,messages: {noResults: '',results: function(){}},autoFocus:true})
```

Comment: you could use css - something like `cursor: pointer` - it would just make your mouse be a pointer the whole time.

Comment: Lookie here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I used `cursor: default`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For CSS:

`#phase { cursor: pointer }`

Or you could use one of these:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Walters' answer didn't work for me.

This is what I had to do to make it work for my particular Autocomplete instance.

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:hover, .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {
  cursor: default; //'Hand' is not a valid value here !!!
}
```

If you want to make the cursor change to something else perhaps specified above the CSS chain, you should use **cursor : pointer** instead

That comment about the 'Hand' value is because I got stuck for days with that, so I figured commenting it here might save someone the pain